# Java cast to object changing other object

Tags: java, sql, arrays, object, casting

```
for (int i = 0; i < info.size(); i++) {
            User b =  (User) info.get(i);

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select ARTIST,TITLE from SONGS WHERE ID = (SELECT ID from USERS WHERE USERNAME = " + "'" + b.Username + "'" + ")");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String artist = rs.getString("ARTIST");
                String title = rs.getString("TITLE");
                b.Songs.add(artist + "-" + title);
            }

            System.out.println(b.getSongs());

        }
```

so this is my code which contains an array of users (info array) each of which have an array called songs which stores each song they own. I want to select the users songs  form the song DB using their username which works fine, then add it to that users array.

However when I run the code this happens:
The info array has 2 users in it.

I get the first user 'Tim'

Get the songs he has: "Queen - We will rock you" and add it to his array, works fine.

Then loop and the next user is selected, but when I add to his array it contains the Queen song, then his songs.

I'm not sure how they are being added to the 2nd users songs array, the SQL works fine and only selects that users songs, but some how b.songs from the previous user is passed into the next user?

Comment: Is `Songs` a static variable by any chance?

Comment: What's the reference `b.Songs`? Do all your `b's` share the same reference?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: The issue may be in your User class, which you didn't show us.

Comment: Is the ID column in the table SONGS, really a foreign key to the ID of the USERS table ? Because I wouldn't name it ID, but USER_ID or something.

Comment: Maybe you should close `rs` in every loop; just add 'rs.close();' to the end of your `for block`.

Comment: Why do you have to cast the result of `info.get`? What is the type of `info`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be joining on the wrong column?

```
Select ...from SONGS WHERE ID = (SELECT ID from USERS where ...)
```

Seems wrong, that SONGS.ID is the ID of the user.

Shouldn't it be

```
Select ...from SONGS WHERE USER_ID = (SELECT ID from USERS where ...)
```

?

Also, die to the way you construct the query string, note that your code will fail if username contains the `'` character.
Moreover, it's vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - a serious security threat.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the issues you've highlighted are the cause of the problem that OP described.  OP's problem is far more likely to have been caused by the word `static` at the wrong place in the `User` class.  But we won't know until he/she shows us the code.